# How to find columns count of csv(Excel) sheet in ETL?

Tags: etl, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

To count the rows of csv file we can use Get Files Rows Count Input in etl. How to find the number columns of a csv file?

Comment: You want to know the # of columns for logging purposes or are trying to do some dynamic processing over this file? Maybe knowing better what are you trying to do people can give alternative suggestions.

Comment: Based on the number of columns I want execute some dynamic process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the first row of the CSV file using Text-File-Input setting header rows to 0. Usually, the first row contains field names.  If you read the whole row into a single field, you can use Split-Field-To-Rows to have a single fieldname per row and the number of rows tells you the number of fields.  There are other ways, but this one easily prepares for a subsequent metadata injection - if that's what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

No Need of Metadata injection , In Split-Field-To-Rows, check "Include rownum in output" and give some name to that Variable. Then apply sort rows on that Variable, use Sample rows, then you will get number of fields  which are present in the file.